cmd/compile: The mechanism by which stack-allocated variable memory within a loop is reused
I have a question about Go optimization.
In Go, even if a variable is declared within a loop, if it does not escape to the heap, the same stack address is reused across iterations instead of allocating a new memory address each time. After escape analysis determines whether a variable escapes, where in cmd/compile is this optimization performed?
Could you please help me with this question?
package main

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        var x int
        println(&x) // output same address
    }
}


Your variable does not escape: The pointer to x does not survive the loop scope, so x can be allocated on the stack and reused by code generation. Note that this is not in the AST, but probably done in the live detection in the stackalloc SSA backend.

Thank you for answering my question!
I found the commit about reusing stack slots for noninterfering spills.
I understand that even if the declaration of a value is represented in the AST, the result of escape analysis showing that the variable does not escape and does not interfere with others allows the same stack area to be reused during SSA optimization.
Is my interpretation correct? Could you please confirm it just to be sure?

Yes, that's basically it. Please mark the useful answers als useful, if they where for you.

Your response was most accurate and informative.
Thank you so much!

Escape analysis determines if a variables escapes to heap or not. It is done here:
https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/escape

Thank you for answering my question!
However, I am asking about the mechanism by which variables allocated to the stack as a result of escape analysis are optimized so that memory is reused. Do you know anything about that?

I am not sure if that would count as an optimization. If a variable declared in a loop does not escape, you can simply reuse the same location next time around. If it escapes, it is interpreted as x=new(int) anyway, using new memory for every iteration.


If a variable declared in a loop does not escape, you can simply reuse the same location next time around

I understand the idea, but I would like to know where the compiler code is that actually allows memory for variables allocated on the stack to be reused.
Also, I would like to know if there is any documentation that can confirm this behavior.
Thank you in advance.

fwiw, all stack data is allocated on function entry. so a variable declared in a loop would be rewritten as the variable declared at the beginning of the function, but reinitialized at every iteration. I doubt you can find code that specifically does what you are asking for. I may be wrong, of course.

Escape analysis determines what is allocated on the stack, but is otherwise unrelated to the reuse of the stack allocation in a loop.   If x escapes, then the stack allocation is a pointer to an  int and that pointer is reused on each iteration.  If x does not escape, then the stack allocation is an int and that int is reused on each iteration of the loop.
It's a necessary optimization to reuse the stack allocation for the body of a loop on each iteration of the loop.  Without that optimization, the stack can grow without bound.
I cannot point to where the feature is implemented, but it's a feature that almost all compiled languages have.  The Go compiler is not doing anything special here.
(The analysis above is a simplification. It's possible that the values are allocated to registers and not the stack.  The register allocation is reused on each iteration of the loop.)

Its occurs in the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree). The syntax tree is analyzed for patterns like non escape of a loop instantiated variable, and does a refactor to reuse the same stack address once it recognizes the pattern in the AST. The AST is what is then used to generate the machine code. I you're familiar with C family of languages specifically, its part of the "make" operation, where pre and post processing on code and object files are performed.

Thank you for answering my question!
I understand that the escape parsing will mark whether the variable is escaped or not on the AST.

refactor to reuse the same stack address once it recognizes the pattern in the AST

Can you please point me to the Go source code or documentation that confirms that “unescaped variables are optimized to be reused with reference to the AST”?

After the escape analysis, the ASTs were as follows.
.   .   FOR-Body
.   .   .   AS-init
.   .   .   .   DCL # main.go:5:7
.   .   .   .   .   NAME-main.x esc(no) Class:PAUTO Offset:0 Addrtaken OnStack Used int tc(1) # main.go:5:7
.   .   .   AS tc(1) # main.go:5:7
.   .   .   .   NAME-main.x esc(no) Class:PAUTO Offset:0 Addrtaken OnStack Used int tc(1) # main.go:5:7
.   .   .   PRINTN tc(1) # main.go:6:10
.   .   .   PRINTN-Args
.   .   .   .   ADDR PTR-*int tc(1) # main.go:6:11
.   .   .   .   .   NAME-main.x esc(no) Class:PAUTO Offset:0 Addrtaken OnStack Used int tc(1)
